# How can I add the level 1 and 2 paragraph name as field in the header text in MS word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm using MS word 2007. I want to add in the header text (on each page) the chapter (level 1) and sub chapter (level 2) name at the top of each page.

I guess I have to add fields for it, but I cannot find the name of fields to use.
Which ones should I use?

Edit:

I think I already found the answer (though still have problems with having multiple sections):

http://en.allexperts.com/q/Microsoft-Word-1058/2008/8/Word-2007-Chapter-Headings.htm

Comment: Are you talking about including that text in header/footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found out but I couldn't add it here.

I needed to add a separate section for each change of paragraph in the header. Disconnect the footer text to not use the previous one, then add a reference as text and copy/change it for every section. Result is 17 different sections.

It would be nice if there were field properties for the 'current' paragraph level 1/2 numbers.